# Von Neumann's Theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\nu, \mu$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures on a space $(X, \mathcal{M})$. Then there exists mutually disjoint measurable sets $X_i \in \mathcal{M}, 1 \leq i \leq 3$ such that following hold:

1. $X = \bigsqcup\limits_{i=1}^3 X_i$
2. $\nu(X_1)=\mu(X_3)=0$
3. On $X_2$ $\nu<<\mu$ and $\mu<<\nu$

(where $ \nu<< \mu$ means $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ $\Leftrightarrow$ if $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(E)=0$ then $\nu(E)=0$)

I have seen a prove of the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem that used the theorem above, anyone can help on how to prove this theorem?

I thought the third condition can be replace by: Exist a nonnegative measurable function $g$ on $X$ such that $g(x)>0, \forall x \in X_2$ and for all $E\subset \mathcal{M}$ with $E \subseteq X$ we have $\nu(E)=\int_E g d \mu$

Comment: Please replace $\nu$ by $\mu$ whereever it is necessary in your formulation of the theorem. It is not correctly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know that. A *symmetric* Lebesgue decomposition - cool.

The proof is a Cute Trick. Which Cute Trick is legal depends on
what you already know - I'm going to assume we know that the dual
of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$ (on a $\sigma$-finite space). If one was
going to use this theorem in proving that the dual of $L^1$ is
$L^\infty$ one could use $L^2$ instead; that requires first
saying WLOG both measures are finite. Anyway:

Define $\Lambda:L^1(\mu+\nu)\to\Bbb C$ by $$\Lambda f=\int f\,d\nu.$$
Now $$|\Lambda f|\le\int|f|\,d\nu\le\int|f|\,d(\mu+\nu),$$so there exists $m\in L^\infty(\mu+\nu)$ so that $$\Lambda f=\int fm\,d(\mu+\nu).$$That is, $$d\nu=m\,d(\mu+\nu).$$This shows that $0\le m\le 1$ a.e.[$\mu+\nu$], so we clean things up by assuming that $0\le m\le 1$. Now we have $$(1-m)\,d\nu=m\,d\mu.$$

Let $X_1=\{m=0\}$, $X_2=\{0<m<1\}$, $X_3=\{m=1\}$. Then $\nu(X_1)=0$, $\mu(X_3)=0$, while on $X_2$ we have $$d\nu=\frac{m}{1-m}\,d\mu$$and $$d\mu=\frac{1-m}{m}\,d\nu.$$